# Python - Unable to get all text from webpage with embedded scripts - Selenium, ChromeDriveManager, BS, requests_html

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am stuck at the following, I want to check the below site in an automate way if there are new packages/shares available (new boxes with a buy option essentially):

https://staking.pocketfives.com/staking/market-place

Given You don't need to log in, it should be okay to scrape afaik.

So far I have read a dozen questions and tried all the methods in the title, however I was unable to make it work. When I use Beautifulsoup or requests_html it just gives me back only the title and one other line of text, not the text in the boxes that I need. The closest I got is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyperclip
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import random

link='https://staking.pocketfives.com/staking/market-place'
CD=ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CD)
driver.get(link)
element=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
time.sleep(random.uniform(6, 12))
    
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(random.uniform(3, 6))        
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(random.uniform(3, 6))

element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'a')
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'c')
driver.quit()
alltext=pyperclip.paste()
print(alltext)
```

I then check every so many minutes in a loop and compare the text from iteration x+1 to iteration x to see if anything has changed.

However this has one big problem, even when scrolling through the website, this does not copy all text! Just the last part of the site.

This is obviously not the most elegant way either, so I am very open to other solutions. I tried making it work with other packages, I just can't seem to run the dynamic scripts on the site correctly, even using render etc. I went into the HTML code but I have trouble understanding it and it consists of a lot of scripts.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are after, but they do have an api. Does this get you what you want?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api2.pocketfives.com/FrontOfficeStake/GetStakeListRequest'
payload= {
'currentPage': '1',
'pageSize': '9999'}
jsonData = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()


df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['stakeList'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
    stakeId  sellerId       sellerName                                                                                                                       sellerImageUrl  venueId venueName                                              venueImageUrl  tournamentId            startTime                                                                title     buyIn  guarantee  markup  offeredPercent  offeredPrice  thresholdPercent  thresholdPrice  purchaseCapPercent  purchaseCapPrice  soldPercent  soldPrice  availablePercent  availablePrice                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    note  hasPassword myTransactionSummary  replyCount
0       108       481       RobinPoker      //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_10/6A79114C-C8C4-4EB1-8476-D1E9E01B1D83.thumb.jpeg.f629f2b49f04b8c9d2c7c272e04cd973.jpeg        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1234  2021-11-01T18:00:00                   Event #61: Deepstack Championship No-Limit Hold'em     600.0        0.0     1.3            50.0        390.00               0.0             0.0                5.00             39.00       50.000     390.00             0.000             0.0                                                                                                                                                                   <p><span style="background-color: rgb(246, 248, 249);">*You are purchasing action for FIRST BULLET ONLY (if player get knocked out and re-enters, you DO NOT have action.)</span></p>        False                 None           0
1        39       480            Pamsi                                      //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_09/pam_gg.thumb.jpg.ce2c1f50b5bc3c805fa4545ab9a3227d.jpg        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1238  2021-11-03T18:00:00              Event #65: MINI Main Event No-Limit Hold’em (freezeout)    1000.0        0.0     1.1            15.0        165.00               0.0             0.0                1.00             11.00       15.000     165.00             0.000             0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   <p>Pamela Balzano</p>        False                 None           0
2        42        23   JonathanLittle                                        //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_09/1004.thumb.JPG.10a21649c3a3cfef8d0ebc5d6f133ec9.JPG        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1240  2021-11-04T18:00:00  Event #67A: MAIN EVENT No-Limit Hold'em World Championship - Day 1A   10000.0        0.0     1.0            10.0       1000.00               0.0             0.0                0.10             10.00       10.000    1000.00             0.000             0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    None        False                 None           0
3       109       481       RobinPoker      //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_10/6A79114C-C8C4-4EB1-8476-D1E9E01B1D83.thumb.jpeg.f629f2b49f04b8c9d2c7c272e04cd973.jpeg        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1244  2021-11-08T20:00:00                 Event #68A: LITTLE ONE FOR ONE DROP No-Limit Hold’em    1111.0        0.0     1.2            50.0        666.60               0.0             0.0                5.00             66.66       50.000     666.60             0.000             0.0                                                                                                                                                                   <p><span style="background-color: rgb(246, 248, 249);">*You are purchasing action for FIRST BULLET ONLY (if player get knocked out and re-enters, you DO NOT have action.)</span></p>        False                 None           0
4        40       480            Pamsi                                      //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_09/pam_gg.thumb.jpg.ce2c1f50b5bc3c805fa4545ab9a3227d.jpg        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1244  2021-11-08T20:00:00                 Event #68A: LITTLE ONE FOR ONE DROP No-Limit Hold’em    1111.0        0.0     1.1            15.0        183.32               0.0             0.0                1.00             12.22       15.000     183.32             0.000             0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   <p>Pamela Balzano</p>        False                 None           0
5        41       480            Pamsi                                      //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_09/pam_gg.thumb.jpg.ce2c1f50b5bc3c805fa4545ab9a3227d.jpg        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1248  2021-11-11T20:00:00                   Event #70A: CRAZY EIGHTS No-Limit Hold'em 8-Handed     888.0        0.0     1.1            15.0        146.52               0.0             0.0                1.00              9.77       15.000     146.52             0.000             0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   <p>Pamela Balzano</p>        False                 None           0
6        59        23   JonathanLittle                                        //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_09/1004.thumb.JPG.10a21649c3a3cfef8d0ebc5d6f133ec9.JPG        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1257  2021-11-15T23:00:00           Event #76: Super Turbo Bounty No-Limit Hold'em (freezeout)   10000.0        0.0     1.0            10.0       1000.00               0.0             0.0                0.10             10.00       10.000    1000.00             0.000             0.0                                                                                                                                                                          <p>*You are purchasing action for FIRST BULLET ONLY (if player gets knocked out and re-enters, you DO NOT have action.)</p><p><br></p><blockquote><br></blockquote><p><br></p>        False                 None           0
7        34        56  Daniel Negreanu  //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_09/239657270_ScreenShot2021-09-10at10_04_11AM.thumb.png.fdefefe1ee4ccfa9148e72b34c59bdf0.png        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1263  2021-11-18T23:00:00                        Event #82: Super High Roller No-Limit Hold'em  250000.0        0.0     1.0            25.0      62500.00               0.0             0.0                0.20            500.00       25.000   62500.00             0.000             0.0  <p>*You are purchasing action for FIRST BULLET ONLY (if player get knocked out and re-enters, you DO NOT have action.</p><p><br></p><p>Are you guys as ready for the WSOP as I am? This is my first public offering for a piece of me in some WSOP action! Ive opened up 25% of of my action at NO MARKUP! Lets make some money and have some fun!</p>        False                 None           0
8        43        23   JonathanLittle                                        //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_09/1004.thumb.JPG.10a21649c3a3cfef8d0ebc5d6f133ec9.JPG        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1267  2021-11-20T23:00:00                              Event #85: HIGH ROLLER No-Limit Hold’em   50000.0        0.0     1.0            20.0      10000.00               0.0             0.0                0.20            100.00       15.700    7850.00             4.300          2150.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    None        False                 None           0
9        52        23   JonathanLittle                                        //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_09/1004.thumb.JPG.10a21649c3a3cfef8d0ebc5d6f133ec9.JPG        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1269  2021-11-21T23:00:00                              Event #87: High Roller No-Limit Hold’em  100000.0        0.0     1.0            70.0      70000.00              69.0         69000.0                0.00              0.00       64.852   64852.00             5.148          5148.0                                                                                                                                                                                                        <p>Please be aware that if this package does not sell out in its entirety, all investors will get a full refund and the package is canceled.</p>        False                 None           0
10       36        56  Daniel Negreanu  //cdn.pocketfives.com/v72/monthly_2021_09/239657270_ScreenShot2021-09-10at10_04_11AM.thumb.png.fdefefe1ee4ccfa9148e72b34c59bdf0.png        1      WSOP  https://cdn.pocketfives.com/staking/common/venue/wsop.png          1269  2021-11-21T23:00:00                              Event #87: High Roller No-Limit Hold’em  100000.0        0.0     1.0            25.0      25000.00               0.0             0.0                0.25            250.00       25.000   25000.00             0.000             0.0                                                                                                                                                                    <p><span style="background-color: rgb(246, 248, 249);">*You are purchasing action for FIRST BULLET ONLY (if player get knocked out and re-enters, you DO NOT have action.</span></p>        False                 None           0
```

Comment: I didn't even think to look for an API, just assumed they wouldn't have one, dumb haha. Thank you so much for this. I think this will do the trick, working on rest of the code now, but from here it seems easy. Thanks again!

Comment: Totally works! As a small followup, where did you find out the API commands etc.? Struggle to find it online or via the site itself. Also, I am used to an API needing an API key, which this one doesn't. Maybe another dumb question, but letting anyone interact with it seems like an open door for overloading it etc. (I now have a 60s check interval, assume thats reasonable right?).

Comment: Go to Dev Tools (shift + ctrl + i) and look under the tabs Network -> XHR -> Headers. You might need to reload the page to see it pop up there.

Comment: That's how you found it, got it. Thank you for helping!